# Add Specific Number of Posts from Category to Homepage

Tags: html, wordpress

please am trying to add specific number of posts (5 posts)  from a category to the homepage but it's not working !

the code am currently using is not showing 5posts instead it's showing 25posts from the category

```
<div id="content"> 
<ul class="disclosure table group"> 
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5&cat=158' ); ?>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<li style="text-align: justify; font-weight: 500; color: #cc3366;">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #cc3366;" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<span style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_title(); ?> </span>
</a> 
</li> 
<?php endwhile; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="content">
<ul class="disclosure table group">
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5&cat=158' ); ?>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
<li style="text-align: justify; font-weight: 500; color: #cc3366;">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #cc3366;" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><span style="font-size: 12px;"><?php the_title(); ?> </span></a>
</li>
  <?php endwhile;
 wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul></div>

Comment: That's the current code am using now but not working correctly

Comment: Please use the edit buton to post code directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this, The cat attribute of wp_query is an array.
So the code should be like bellow

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'cat' => array(158),
        'posts_per_page'=>5,
);
$catquery = new WP_Query($args); 
 while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); 

//your code goes here

 endwhile; 
 wp_reset_postdata();
```

Try the code , then let me know the result.Thanks

Comment: Still showing the same 25 posts not working for 5 posts

Comment: Can you tell me , in which file you have added the code?

Comment: Added the code to my post-default.php to show category posts on homepage

Comment: I think, previous query is not reset. So try to add wp_reset_query(); before my code then let me know the result. If this works then defiantly previous query hampers this query.